# CPU / DTUs getting maxed out on Azure SQL Database, but top queries less than 1% and database only a few MB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I just launched an Azure SQL Database, and the DTU and CPU usage is behaving strangely.  The database is only receiving about 30 requests per minute, and the CPU/DTU will be extremely low for hours, and then jump up to 100% and stay there (with no increase in the number of requests that triggers this).  When I click to view the top queries, none of them are above 1% cpu usage.  I started out on a 5 DTU plan, and yesterday upgraded to 20 DTUs and the same behavior is occurring.  Any idea what else might cause the DTU/CPU to get maxed out?  See images below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSlC2.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIInz.png

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Joe

EDIT: I'm getting closer, I found these repeated entries in the error log.  (about 8 - 10 per SECOND)

"The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request."

The thing is, the App Service that queries the database is only doing simple selects, updates, and inserts... none of which uses any complex WHERE IN statement.  Furthermore, every query is wrapped in a try/catch block, and I'm never seeing an exception like this.

Where could these large queries be originating from?

Comment: Sounds like you've found the error. My guess is that your App Service is doing something other than what you imagine. Try/catch blocks are great, but what are you doing with exceptions within the catch? If you're swallowing them, then it does you no good. I recommend adding Application Insights (which is free for up to a certain data volume) to your web app to get an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You are only seeing the CPU component of the DTU  graph, what about the "Data IO" and the "Log IO" components? Look at the top 5 queries on the 3 sections, and let me know if you find a query that start with "SELECT Statman ...". If you see that, then the Auto Update Statistics process is creating those DTU spikes.

Comment: I saw that with mine. Any recommendation on what should I do?

Comment: @Sam Disable autoupdate statistics and do maintenance of indexes and statistics during non-business hours using Azure Automation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install the sp_whoisactive script so that you can see what's going on more easily:

http://whoisactive.com/